# Why is it possible to refer to a previously undefined variable in the KEYWORD package?

Tags: common-lisp

Referring to a variable that was not previously defined will result in an error: `The variable X is unbound` (SBCL's error message). However, referring to a previously undefined variable in the `KEYWORD` package will not result in any error. For example, `KEYWORD:XYZ` magically has a value of `:XYZ`, even though the user did not previously define and export the variable. Why does this happen? How is it possible that a variable was automatically created on the fly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Lisp reader interns symbols which begin with a [package marker](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_p.htm#package_marker) in the `KEYWORD` package; the package marker is a colon by default. Symbols interned in the `KEYWORD` package are automatically made external. From [11.1.2.3.1 of the HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abca.htm):

> The KEYWORD package is treated differently than other packages in that special actions are taken when a symbol is interned in it. In particular, when a symbol is interned in the KEYWORD package, it is automatically made to be an external symbol and is automatically made to be a constant variable with itself as a value.

Comment: Is it possible to define a package (e.g. `MY-KEYWORD`) to have these "special actions"? e.g. when a symbol is interned in the `MY-KEYWORD` package, it is automatically made to be an external symbol and is automatically made to be a constant variable with itself as a value.

Comment: Not in any portable way, no.