# What should be the argument type when using "in-package"?

Tags: common-lisp

I have defined a package: `(defpackage my-package (:use cl) (:export my-function))`. When using `in-package` for that package, what should be the type of the argument given to `in-package`?

The [Common Lisp HyperSpec](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_in_pkg.htm) says:

> **in-package** name => package
>
> **Arguments and Values:**
>
> name---a string designator; not evaluated.
>
> package---the package named by name.

I have tried the following:

- `(in-package my-package)` — ✓
- `(in-package :my-package)` — ✓
- `(in-package #:my-package)` — ✓
- `(in-package "MY-PACKAGE")` — ✓

All of the above appear to be valid. What is the difference between the above? Which of the above should I use?

In addition, I noticed this:

- `(in-package 'my-package)` — ✗

  Error in SBCL:

  ```
  ; compiling file "/path/to/my-program.lisp" (written 12 MAR 2021 01:23:45 AM):
  ; compiling (IN-PACKAGE (QUOTE MY-PACKAGE))
  ; file: /path/to/my-program.lisp
  ; in: IN-PACKAGE 'MY-PACKAGE
  ;     (IN-PACKAGE 'MY-PACKAGE)
  ; 
  ; caught ERROR:
  ;   (during macroexpansion of (IN-PACKAGE 'MY-PACKAGE))
  ;   'MY-PACKAGE is not a string designator
  ```

Why is it correct to use a keyword or uninterned symbol, but not a symbol?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The argument to `in-package` should be a [string designator](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/26_glo_s.htm#string_designator), which is a character, symbol, or string.

In your examples:

- `my-package` is a symbol
- `:my-package` is a keyword (automatically interned and exported, [as discussed in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69231241/6879826))
- `#:my-package` is an [uninterned symbol](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/02_dhe.htm)
- `"MY-PACKAGE"` is a string

All of these are string designators, but the expression `'my-package` is *not* a string designator (it is not a symbol); it is shorthand for the expression `(quote my-package)`. The expression `(quote my-package)` does *evaluate* to a symbol, but.... Recall that the documentation for `in-package` (which is quoted above in the posted question) stipulates that its argument is *not evaluated*. This is because `in-package` is a macro. With all of the versions which worked, a symbol (or a string) was passed to the macro, but with `'my-package` the unevaluated form `(quote my-package)` was passed. This explains the error message shown above:

> ; compiling (IN-PACKAGE (QUOTE MY-PACKAGE))
> ; file: /path/to/my-program.lisp
> ; in: IN-PACKAGE 'MY-PACKAGE
> ;     (IN-PACKAGE 'MY-PACKAGE)
> ;
> ; caught ERROR:
> ;   (during macroexpansion of (IN-PACKAGE 'MY-PACKAGE))
> ;   'MY-PACKAGE is not a string designator

Note that by default the Lisp reader will upcase symbol names, but strings are case sensitive and when used as string designators must be appropriately cased.

Comment: Which should I use? From my understanding, I should prefer the uninterned symbol because it does not pollute the current or keyword namespaces (as when using a symbol or keyword).

Comment: Take your pick. Any string designator is fine; I prefer keywords or uninterned symbols to strings since then I don't have to worry about case. Using uninterned symbols is a marginal gain over using plain keywords, but I usually use them anyway.